# Invalid Identifier in Update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to update some codes in a table where they have been left blank. My temp table has all the codes in there and I am trying to join on ID number. I believe I am getting the Invalid Identifier variable because I declared the variable from my temp table before I join the table but I have tried a few variations and Cant seem to get it work. Here is what I have so far. I realize this is pretty novice but I am stuck.

```
UPDATE table_1 t1
SET t1.code = t2.code
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_2 t2
                      WHERE t2.id_number = t1.id_number
                      AND t1.code = ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_1 t1
SET t1.code = t2.code
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t2.id_number = 
**t1_id_number** AND t1.code = ' ')
```

change **t1_id_number**
to t1.id_number

Comment: You will get the same error as the OP: the name `t2` is visible only in the subquery in the `where` clause, it is not visible in the `set` clause.

Answer (score 0):

One method in Oracle is to use `merge`, but you can do this with an `update` as well:

```
UPDATE table_1 t1
    SET t1.code = (SELECT t2.code
                   FROM table_2 t2
                   WHERE t2.id_number = t1.id_number
                  )
WHERE (t1.code = ' ' OR t1.code IS NULL) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table_2 t2
              WHERE t2.id_number = t1.id_number
             );
```

Notes:

- `t2` is not understood in the `SET` because it is never defined.
- The condition on `t1.code` should go directly in the `WHERE` and not in the subquery -- the condition really has nothing to do with the subquery.
- I added a `NULL` check as well as a space check.
- I believe you want `t1.id_number` rather than `t1_id_number`.